# Bounty not awarded?

Tags: support, bounty

For reference, [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/178014/vpn-profile-working-in-iphone/178178#178178) is the question, in well, question.

The originally poster of the question created the bounty about a week ago. I quickly saw it and put some effort into the answer since a.) I wanted 50 more rep and b.) I remembered there being a number of badges related to bounties. The question poster quickly accepted my answer and i gathered a total of four up-votes.

The question only has one other answer with a single up-vote. The bounty ended yesterday and the grace period ended about an hour ago, yet I still have not received my rep. I double checked the bounty rules and realize the person who posted the question could/should have formally rewarded the bounty to me, but under a backup rule since I had the highest number of up-votes (over 2 total) and was the accepted answer, I am supposed to receive the full bounty.

Therefore, anyone know why I have not reaped the rewards of my sweet bounty hunting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Solution found: wait another few hours and the bounty comes through. Nevermind!

Comment: yes - various awarding actions run as scripts at particular times of day, so waiting a bit is usually the fix. This works for some badges as well :-)